# gdb tui -- turn off printing function parameters for asm layout

Tags: c++, c, assembly, gdb, tui

Gdb in tui mode in asm layout prints something like:

```
<address+0> <namespace:func(int, int, ..... many many many parameters)+0>  instruction1
<address+4> <namespace:func(int, int, ..... many many many parameters)+4>  instruction2
<address+8> <namespace:func(int, int, ..... many many many parameters)+8>  instruction3
......etc.
```

To have the instructions (rather than this long demangled `func` name) in front of me I have to press the key right arrow `->` for a very long time. The `End` key button does not work. What's worse is that very often gdb tui "jumps" to the beginning of the line -- all by itself. So I have to press the key right arrow `->` again to go back to the instructions.

So this makes debugging with gdb tui close to impossible. Is there any solution to that? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16941818/4781940), unfortunately, did not help. I also tried different commands for turning demangling off like `set print asm-demangle off`, but it also did not help.

Comment: Sounds like [this](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15580) gdb bug.